# Run time change layout with preloaded data or move view in android fragment or activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation

i am downloading the text data,images,video and checkbox create runtime and display it in layout with different position but the porblem is if i change the layout runtime than the data redwonloading i want to use the existing download data,image and video and display it in landscape layout. how it is work.

**portrait_layout view**

[image]

**landscape_layout view**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you turn your screen, the activity recreates. So if you download your data in `onCreate` or in `onResume`, it redownloads. Store the data in db and use `onRestoreInstanceState()` to prevent redownload.

Answer (score 0):

If its a fragment then just use setRetainInstance(true) and you data will still be there, If its an Activity then use android:configChanges="orientation" in AndroidManifest.